# Retrieve Password DNN

Tags: c#, .net, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module

we are using dot net nuke portal.

when user clicks Retrieve Password he gets email with From: test@testmail.my 
I want to change this email but I can't find the place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks liam for the quick response but I notice that

the email that include in the “form “ is the admin email.
    So I edit my account (admin) to the new mail.
    Now it's working

Thanks

Comment: Yeah, sorry, that's what I meant - it's the portal admin mail address. I'd nomrally edit it at portal level rather than individual accounts, but both achieve the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing this from the root portal or a child one?

As if it's the child one, you can change this in the portals setup via accessing it in the root portal -> portal options.